# PowerShell piping failing - ActiveDirectory cmdlets

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-cmdlet, piping

Part of a script I'm writing in my test setup involves disabling user accounts based on the department attribute.
I can do this with the following:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter "Department -eq 'SomeDept'" | foreach {Set-ADUser $_ -Enabled 0}
```

However, this doesn't work for some reason:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter "Department -eq 'SomeDept'" | Set-Aduser $_ -Enabled 0
```

The error returned is "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null.....", indicating a problem with my usage of $_.

Why does the foreach implementation of this work, whereas the simpler version fail on account of the object being piped through?

Comment: Remove `$_` from the second example, the pipeline automatically binds the `ADUser` objects returned from `Get-ADUser` to `-Identity`

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen - That works nicely. If I don't use `$_` for the `foreach` example, I get prompted for `-Identity`. Does `foreach` effectively "get in the way" of the binding?

Comment: Yes and no, the objects coming in through the pipeline is bound to `ForEach-Object`'s `-InputObject`, each of which is then auto-assigned to `$_` inside the scriptblock

Comment: So if there's no `$_` used, there is nothing to assign to, hence the prompt for `-Identity`?

Comment: Correct. `ForEach-Object` is mostly handy if the `cmdlet` that you pipe to don't support pipeline processing, or if you need to manipulate some property or value before binding and are not interested in changed the actual incoming object. In your case it's highly unnecessary